# Simple Javascript Image Gallery - with pagination dots and Mutliple Instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, gallery

I'm new to Javascript, but I've been teaching myself CSS and some php so I'm hoping to learn a bit. I've been looking all over the last couple days to figure out what I want, hopefully this isn't a dumb question.

I'm trying to build mini-image galleries for a page of porfolio projects of mine. I've got a page of about 8 large images - each one for a different project. I'm trying to get it where if you click on an image it will load the next image of that project (Mission accomplished! I've gotten that with a code I found online)

But I also want pagination dots (basically, images of circles), like I've seen on other websites, to represent the images in the set. So if there's three images of a project, you'll see three dots and clicking on the third dot takes you to the third image -- and that dot image replaces with the 'selected dot' image. Make sense?

I've been looking all day for scripts and examples of how to do this, and this is as far as my Javascript has gotten. This is the script for the first project. With the others I input the same script, but change the variables. img1 becomes img2 then img3 and so on. Can anyone tell what's wrong?

```
<div class="project" id="proj1">

<script type="text/javascript">
var img1 = [ 
    "img/portf/tiger1.jpg", 
    "img/portf/tiger2.jpg", 
    "img/portf/tiger3.jpg" 
];
img1.current = 0;
function showImage1(i) { 
$('#imag1').fadeOut( function() { 
this.src = img1[img1.current]; 
$(this).fadeIn(); 
}); 
}

function NextImage1() { 
img1.current = (img1.current+1) % img1.length; 
showImage1(img1.current); 
}

function PreviousImage1() { 
if (--img1.current < 0) { img1.current = img1.length - 1; } 
showImage1(img1.current);
}
onload = function(){ 
showImage1(0);
};

</script>

<div class="projname">

<div class="ProjectTitle">
Tigercat Website
</div>
<div class="PaginationButtons">
<a href="javascript:showImage1(0)"><img src="img/active.gif" /></a> 
<a href="javascript:showImage1(1)"><img src="img/inactive.gif" /></a> 
<a href="javascript:showImage1(2)"><img src="img/inactive.gif" /></a>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<div class="projwindow">
<a href="javascript:NextImage1()">
<img src="img/portf/tiger1.jpg" name="Tigerc" width="800" height="600" id="imag1" />
</a>

</div>
</div>
```

You can see what I have so far here:  http://www.gmisen.com
Thanks so much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the greatest learning experience, but you can easily achieve this with the jQuery cycle plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html (take a look at the pager example)

here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/69LNJ/

**HTML**

```
<div class="slideshow">
<img src="http://flickholdr.com/400/400/cat/bw">
<img src="http://flickholdr.com/400/400/cat/bw/1">
<img src="http://flickholdr.com/400/400/cat/bw/2">
</div>​
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('.slideshow').before('<div id="nav">').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 'fast',
        timeout: 0,
        pager: '#nav'
    });
})​;
```

**CSS**

```
#nav{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#nav a{
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  text-indent: -1000px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#nav a.activeSlide{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

​